# How to add red borders around any invalid input index in mapped inputs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a modal which maps each element of the object `newCompanies` to a row:

```
        {newCompanies.map((company, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div
                className="side-by-side"
              >
                  <ModalInput
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    value={company.name}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      this.editCompanyArr(index, "name", e, "validName")
                    }
                  ></ModalInput>
                  <ModalInput
                    type="text"
                    id="website"
                    value={company.website}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      this.editCompanyArr(
                        index,
                        "website",
                        e,
                        "validWebsite"
                      )
                    }
                  ></ModalInput>
                      <ModalInput
                        type="text"
                        id="sector"
                        value={company.class}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          this.editCompanyArr(
                            index,
                            "sector",
                            e,
                            "validSector"
                          )
                        }
                      ></ModalInput>
```

`ModalInput` is defined in `styles.js`:

```
export const ModalInput = styled.input`
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #f5f6f9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f6f9;
  height: 100%;
  width: ${props => props.width || 'auto'};
`;
```

And this is the function which checks whether a user entered a correct value. so for example, if the name contains numbers, the value of `validName` will become `false`:

```
  editCompanyArr(i, obj, e, stateObject) {
      const { newCompanies, validName } = this.state;
      if (e.target.value.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$") != null) {
        this.setState({ [stateObject]: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ [stateObject]: false });
      }
      //edited out more body to update value in newCompanies
}
```

How can I ensure that if a user enters an incorrect input for any mapped row, that only that particular input and not the rest of them get a red border?

Comment: I updated my answer, consider taking a look and giving some feedback! Greetings

Comment: Can you pass the id through the loop? Is it possible? What's the structure of the `newCompanies` object. The best and easiest way will be to store the id with error status in state and pass props to `styled-component` based on the error value & id for comparison. Below answers are way to confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

Define the state variables you are going to need, I made a state variable for input values `name` and `age` (as an example). I also defined state for the classes so that when this value changes, the component re-renders and the border color updates.

I set some initial `className` values so that the first render is with a red border (`border-danger` in Bootstrap).

```js
// initial classes
const initialClassNames = {
  name: "border-danger",
  age: "border-danger",
};

// needed states
const [classNames, setClassNames] = useState(initialClassNames);
const [values, setValues] = useState({ name: "", age: 0 });
```

Then I assigned the different fields with their own specifications that I want to map later. Note how the state values are bound to the input field specifications.

```js
// specs for all input fields
const inputFields = [
  {
    inputLabel: "Name", // label for the input field
    inputName: "name", // name
    inputValue: values.name, // value
    inputClassName: classNames.name // className
  },
  {
    inputLabel: "Age",
    inputName: "age",
    inputValue: values.age,
    inputClassName: classNames.age
  }
];
```

In the `return()`, I map over all the fields and provide the wanted JSX.

```js
return (
  <div className="container mt-3">
    {inputFields.map((f, i) => {
      return (
        <div className="mb-5" key={i}>
          <label htmlFor={`${f.inputName}${i}`}>{f.inputLabel}</label>
          <input
            id={`${f.inputName}${i}`}
            name={f.inputName}
            value={f.inputValue}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className={`form-control ${f.inputClassName}`}
          ></input>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

This is how you would want to handle your change events for your inputs:

```js
// handleChange for inputs
const handleChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

And you could do some validation like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // validate name
  if (values.name) {
    setClassNames((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, name: (prevState.name = "border-success") };
    });
  } else {
    setClassNames((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, name: (prevState.name = "border-danger") };
    });
  }

  // validate age
  if (parseInt(values.age, 10)) {
    setClassNames((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, age: (prevState.age = "border-success") };
    });
  } else {
    setClassNames((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, age: (prevState.age = "border-danger") };
    });
  }
}, [values.name, values.age]);
```

In the `useEffect()` function, I check if the input fields are correctly filled in every time the input values change (component re-renders). Depending on that, I change the class names to the wanted value. I used bootstrap classes (border-danger, border-success) in this example but you could do this with your own styling if you want.

If you only want the validation to happen on for example a button `onClick()`, this would also be possible.

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-allen-q57xy?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this is to add a CSS class that will give them the outline you want. Keep a flag for each input in the state, and set them to true on submit if it's value is invalid. Then you can clear the error when the user clicks into the input or types.

JSX:

```
const App = () => {
  const [inputError, setInputError] = useState(false)
  const refs = {
    exampleInput: null
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => {
      const exampleInput = this.refs.exampleInput
      const exampleInputVal = exampleInput.value
      if(exampleInputVal) {
        // It's valid! Submit it
      } else {
        // INVALID! Set error state: 
        setInputError(true)
      }
    }}>
      <input 
        className={inputError ? 'error' : ''} 
        ref={el => { refs.exampleInput = el }}
        onChange={e => setInputError(false)}
        onFocus{e => setInputError(false)}
      />
    </form>
  )
}
```

CSS:

```css
input.error, 
input:focus.error {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
}
```

Comment: Will this check the input as the user types as well?

Comment: @user2555 no it will not. If the user ever types, the errors on that input will be cleared. It currently only check validity and sets errors when the user attempts to submit the form. If you instead want to always check validity as the user types, add that to the onChange callback on the input.